# step-by-step replication data from local MySQL master to Google Cloud SQL slave

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

I need to replicate data from local database master (using MySQL 5.6) to Google Cloud SQL slave. I read the google instructions and I did it until now:

- Installed MySQL 5.6 on local machine and created local instance, database and tables;
- Set up to use binary files (it´s necessary for replication);
- Created user "replica" to have access to master;
- Created backup.sql file using mysqldump and I followed google instructions;
- Upload this file to Google storage bucket;
- Created 1º generation instance in google Cloud SQL;
- Created database into 1º generation instance;
- Restored backup.sql into database;

Next steps in google instruction is type the code into Google Shell "ACCESS_TOKEN="...

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{"name": "[INTERNAL_MASTER_INSTANCE_NAME]",
          "region": "[REGION_NAME]",
          "databaseVersion": "[EXTERNAL_MASTER_DATABASE_VERSION]",
          "onPremisesConfiguration": {"hostPort": "[IP_ADDRESS:PORT]"}}' \
 -X POST \
 https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances
```

But I have a error message "400 - Invalid value for: 5.6.39 is not a valid value". Where can I find "databaseVersion": "[EXTERNAL_MASTER_DATABASE_VERSION]" in MySQL? Someone has step-by-step to configure local database using MySQL to replicate data to Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Configuring External Masters](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master#creating_the_external_master_configuration) documenation, you have 2 options for the databaseVersion:

> For databaseVersion, provide the MySQL version of the master instance:
>   `MYSQL_5_5` or `MYSQL_5_6`

Since you are inserting 5.6.39 instead, it's triggering the 400 error.